# SAM CLI for CI/CD other than Cloud Formation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

Is it possible to use SAM CLI (or any other tool known to mankind) to deploy a lambda function with defined triggers, memory and timeout limits set, etc. the way SAM CLI is able to do it using Cloud Formation (or even in a better way)?

Currently I'm using TravisCI to deploy my lambda functions, but that's really just a better zip uploader to AWS, as I can't define any triggers for the lambda function the way I can do it through SAM (Serverless Application Model).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since asking the question I came across diferrent useful tools to deploy configured Lambda functions:

- [serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/)

  > All-in-one development & monitoring of auto-scaling apps on AWS Lambda
- [AWS CDK](https://aws.amazon.com/cdk/)

  > Define cloud infrastructure using familiar programming languages

Answer (score 1):

I would look into leveraging AWS Code pipeline, Codebuild, Code deploy for you serverless functions CI/CD. Sam also has some awesome baked in tools for leveraging code deploy under the hood to enable things like weighted roll outs canary deploys etc.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-safe-lambda-deployments
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-safe-aws-lambda-deployments-with-aws-codedeploy/

For specifying things like memory, triggers, timeouts this would all be done in cloudformation template as you mentioned and this is best practice.